# Install Mono and Monodevelop on CentOS 5.x/6.x

Tags: linux, mono, centos, monodevelop

I am trying to install Mono and Monodevelop on a CentOS 5.9 environment.

I have tried the following instructions, with no luck.

http://fealves78.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/install-mono-and-monodevelop-on-centos.html

Can anyone suggest an alternative to the the above link.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On these systems, I typically install Mono from source. It is a bit more work but you do not have to rely on dated or broken packages that may or may not be maintained. Also, it makes it easy to upgrade to the latest versions of Mono.

The instructions below were tested on CentOS 6.4.

Head over to `/usr/src` as root

```
su
cd /usr/src
```

Ensure GCC and friends are installed (to build the Mono source code)

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ libtool bison autoconf automake
```

Grab and unpack the Mono source code

```
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.0.7.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf mono-3.0.7.tar.bz2
```

Build and install Mono

```
cd mono-3.0.7
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

Verify that you have a working Mono installation with `mono --version` and `mcs --version`

Build the GDI+ compatibility layer (required for System.Drawing)

```
yum install glib2-devel libX11-devel pixman-devel fontconfig-devel freetype-devel libexif-devel libjpeg-devel libtiff-devel libpng-devel giflib-devel

cd /usr/src
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/libgdiplus/libgdiplus-2.10.9.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf libgdiplus-2.10.9.tar.bz2
cd libgdiplus-2.10.9
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

That is it for Mono but building MonoDevelop is another story...

Build Gtk-Sharp

```
yum install gtk2-devel libglade2-devel

cd /usr/src
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/gtk-sharp212/gtk-sharp-2.12.8.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf gtk-sharp-2.12.8.tar.bz2
cd gtk-sharp-2.12.8
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

Unfortunately, I do not think there is a proper source tarball of gnome-sharp that is new enough for what we need. So, we will get it from the Git repository.

```
yum install pango-devel atk-devel libgnome-devel libgnomecanvas-devel libgnomeui-devel git svn libtool

cd /usr/src
git clone git://github.com/mono/gnome-sharp
cd gnome-sharp
./bootstrap-2.24 --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

Same for Mono Addins...

```
cd /usr/src
git clone git://github.com/mono/mono-addins
cd mono-addins
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

Finally, we can build MonoDevelop itself.

```
cd /usr/src
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/monodevelop/monodevelop-3.1.1.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf monodevelop-3.1.1.tar.bz2
cd monodevelop-3.1.1
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
./configure --prefix=/usr --select
make && make install
```

You should now see MonoDevelop in the Programming menu under Applications!

Now that we are doing all this fun Git stuff, it is easy enough to upgrade to the latest (pre-release) version of Mono any time we want...

First time checking out of Git:

```
cd /usr/src
git clone git://github.com/mono/mono
cd mono
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

To just upgrade to the latest version (after the first time building from Git)

```
cd /usr/src/mono
git pull
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

If you do not want the bleeding edge, you can use Git to check-out more stable branches of Mono instead. I will leave that as an exercise for Wikipedia.

Comment: when I am trying to make `gnome-sharp` it's failing with the error `Could not find a part of the path "/usr/src/share/gapi-2.0/glib-api.xml"`. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Justin I get these errors when make and make installing the gtk-sharp:make[2]: *** [gtk-sharp-docs.zip] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/gtk-sharp-2.12.8/doc'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/gtk-sharp-2.12.8'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: I was able to install this on CentOS 5.9.  Mono 3.4.0, however, did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900575/install-mono-and-monodevelop-on-centos-5-x-6-x/18133056#18133056

Comment: I get all the way to building monodevelop, but I was hoping to use the version 5.10 of the IDE.  But when I go to run make, I get an error that it can't find nuget

Comment: this is brilliant, but it has aged. the version mismatches are worse than MS DLL hell by now. We should really have a how-to page like this here on the new SO documentation, on the monodevelop docs, that is kept up to date otherwise installing this on a recent centos/fedora/rhel is a nightmare. I'm at it for the third night in a row, currently stuck with the gtk-sharp step on an RHEL7, getting "Only <glib.h> can be included directly" from make...

Answer (score 4):

In order for gtk-sharp to build I had to set the following environment variable:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Without this, the configure script was looking for csc.exe

Answer (score 2):

On these systems, I typically install Mono from source. It is a bit more work but you do not have to rely on dated or broken packages that may or may not be maintained.

The instructions below were tested on CentOS 5.9.

Because of limitations in the installed versions of Glib and GTK+, the newest version of GTK# you can compile on RHEL5 (CentOS 5.x) is 2.10.4. With this version of GTK#, the newest version of MonoDevelop that you can build is 2.0 (not even 2.2).

You can still run very recent versions of Mono though. I have CentOS 5.x boxes serving up ASP.NET MVC3 apps.

Head over to `/usr/src` as root

```
su
cd /usr/src
```

Ensure GCC and friends are installed (to build the Mono source code)

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ libtool bison autoconf automake
```

Grab and unpack the Mono source code

```
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.0.7.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf mono-3.0.7.tar.bz2
```

Build and install Mono

```
cd mono-3.0.7
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

Verify that you have a working Mono installation with `mono --version` and `mcs --version`

Build the GDI+ compatibility layer (required for System.Drawing)

```
yum install glib2-devel libX11-devel pixman-devel fontconfig-devel freetype-devel libexif-devel libjpeg-devel glib2-devel libtif-devel libpng-devel giflib-devel

cd /usr/src
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/libgdiplus/libgdiplus-2.10.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf libgdiplus-2.10.tar.bz2
```