# configure: error: You need to install either mono or .Net

Tags: mono, monodevelop, gtk#, centos6

I want to install monodevelop in centos 6.3,but when i configure the gtk-sharp-2.12.21,i get the error:
**checking for csc.exe... no
configure: error: You need to install either mono or .Net**

but,i have installed the mono,also have exported the path.

**Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.1 (tarball 2013年 09月 06日 星期五 09:20:28 CST)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen**

can anybody tell me the reason.
Thinks!

Comment: how did you install mono? on what prefix?

Comment: @knocte --prefix=/usr

Comment: you can try set PKG_CONFIG_PATH manually. source: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18133056/724908)