# error encountered installing mono and monodevelop on centos 6

Tags: linux, mono

I have been following sintructions for installing mono and monodevelop 
on centos 6 found in this web page :
[Install Mono and Monodevelop on CentOS 5.x/6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900575/install-mono-and-monodevelop-on-centos-5-x-6-x)

I have stalled on one of the steps explained below

```
yum install pango-devel atk-devel libgnome-devel libgnomecanvas-devel libgnomeui-devel git svn libtool

cd /usr/src
git clone git://github.com/mono/gnome-sharp
cd gnome-sharp
./bootstrap-2.24 --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

When I run the make command in gnome-sharp I get this error :-

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/gnome-sharp'
Making all in sources
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/gnome-sharp/sources'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/gnome-sharp/sources'
Making all in art
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/gnome-sharp/art'
/usr/bin/mcs -debug -define:GTK_SHARP_2_6 -define:GTK_SHARP_2_8 -define:GNOME_SHARP_2_16 -define:GNOME_SHARP_2_20 -define:GNOME_SHARP_2_24 -nowarn:0169,0612,0618 -unsafe -out:art-sharp.dll -target:library /usr/lib  -r:Mono.Cairo   generated/*.cs  AssemblyInfo.cs
error CS2001: Source file `/usr/lib' could not be found
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
make[2]: *** [art-sharp.dll] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/gnome-sharp/art'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/gnome-sharp'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It looks as if the Makefile process is broken at least to me. Any help gratefully received.

-roddy

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install Mono from source anymore, there are now official packages: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#centos-fedora-and-derivatives