# Install Mono in red hat 5

Tags: mono, monodevelop, redhat

I have been looking in the mono-project website the dependencies to install mono and the sources but I haven't found anything.

Does anyone know how to install mono udner a red hat linux 5 32-bit environment? Maybe the sources are deprecated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have found how to do it. All the mono repository is in:

http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/

And then you follow this guideline:

[Install Mono and Monodevelop on CentOS 5.x/6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900575/install-mono-and-monodevelop-on-centos-5-x-6-x)