# --select option for linux ./configure command

Tags: centos

I am new to Linux and wanted to install MonoDevelop on my CentOS 6 VM.  I found this question: [Install Mono and Monodevelop on CentOS 5.x/6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900575/install-mono-and-monodevelop-on-centos-5-x-6-x) and was following the instructions outlined there but when I go to this step:

```
cd /usr/src
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/monodevelop/monodevelop-3.1.1.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf monodevelop-3.1.1.tar.bz2
cd monodevelop-3.1.1
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
./configure --prefix=/usr --select
make && make install
```

Specifically the `./configure --prefix=/usr --select` command, I got the following error on my system:

```
configure: error: unrecognized option: `--select'
Try `./configure --help' for more information
```

I typed `./configure --help` in the terminal, but saw no `--select` option.
What does the `--select` option do?

Comment: That's not an option I'm familiar with as a standard option and if it doesn't work I'm going to guess it was a typo in the original. If you want to ask the author of the answer add a comment to the answer asking them.