# "configure: error: mcs Not found" during configure mono-addins on CentOS

Tags: linux, mono, centos, monodevelop

I'm trying to install MonoDevelop 4 on CentOS 7 as described in this post: [Install Mono and Monodevelop on CentOS 5.x/6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900575/install-mono-and-monodevelop-on-centos-5-x-6-x/17034163#17034163), but when I'm trying to execute 
`./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr` in mono-addins src directory, I get the error:

```
Running autoconf ...
Running ./configure --prefix=/usr ...
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '0' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '0' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking for gmcs... no
configure: error: mcs Not found
```

mcs compiler was installed successfully, and if I execute

`mcs --version`

it returns

`Mono C# compiler version 4.0.3.0`

In other examples of autoconf output I see that checking for gmcs returns something like `/usr/local/bin/gmcs` or `/usr/bin/gmcs`, but on my system after compiling mono I don't have `gmcs` at all.

What is the difference between mcs and gmcs, and where can I find second?

Comment: how did you install mono? what prefix did you use? if you followed those instructions, there should be a /usr/bin/mcs binary in your system which the configure of mono-addins finds

Comment: if `mcs --version` works, what does `which mcs` return?

Comment: @knocte Thank you for your interest in my question. Now I have deleted the VM where this problem arose. I tried to install monodevelop on KDE from the repository, and I did not succeed. So I tried to compile the source, and it also did not work. But then I installed Gnome and install monodevelop from the repository was successful. Maybe monodevelop and KDE incompatible?

Comment: why don't you answer my question?

Answer (score 2):

mono-gmcs was an interim compiler before moving to mcs.  I ran into this problem ("configure: error: No gmcs C# compiler found") while trying to install Bless (a mono/C# hex editor) on Centos 7.  Not sure if this is the answer on other distros, but I added a symbolic link with ln -s mcs gmcs, so that the script that is looking for gmcs will find it, but it will redirect to mcs, the current mono C# compiler.  Both should be in /usr/local.  For Bless, there was also a dependency on "scrollkeeper", which I took care of with a yum install scrollkeeper.

Comment: I run the same problem installing Bless in CentOS 7 too. Your answer solved my problem but in my case mcs was in /usr/bin and Bless was installed to /usr/local/bin. Additionally, I was not missing scrollkeeper dependency since I had installed dependecies (rarian-compat, mono-devel, gtk-sharp2-devel) before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I uses Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS; and it also does not have mcs. I actaully needed it for bless. so I install mcs using

```
sudo apt install mono-mcs
```

so now

```
which mcs
```

now returns /usr/bin/mcs

---

For bless to work you also need to install cmake; using

```
sudo apt inztall cmake gtk-sharp2 nunit-console xsltproc
```

and follow the instruction in the readme file to install bless; i.e.

```
git clone https://github.com/afrantzis/bless
meson setup build
ninja -C build
sudo ninja -C build install
```