# Xamarin development on Centos 6

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, cross-platform, mobile-development

I would like to ask for a guide on how can I develop cross platform applications using Xamarin in Centos 6.

I spent the whole day following this: [Install Mono and Monodevelop on CentOS 5.x/6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900575/install-mono-and-monodevelop-on-centos-5-x-6-x)

So I can install Mono and Monodevelop. But now, I am blocked because I can't understand how I am going to use this tools so I can create Android and iOS applications.

Can I do Xamarin development in Centos 6? If yes, I would also like to ask for good resources because it seems that there are very few tutorials for Xamarin especially in Centos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the complexity of Linux distribution and various dependencies, Xamarin only supports Windows and OS X as supported development platforms. Thus, you either use a Windows machine, or a Mac.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. So what is Monodevelop? I thought I can use monodevelop to develop xamarin cross platform application.

Comment: @MagentoUser MonoDevelop is the open source part of Xamarin Studio, so it can only develop Mono based apps (GTK# and XSP). Xamarin is the umbrella for commercial products (Mac, iOS and Android).

Comment: @MagentoUser how do you expect a firm to say something like this? They have to be quiet in certain cases to run the business. But clearly they could support Linux, once there are enough reasons.

Comment: @LexLi in fact there is an official bug report open since 2011 about supporting Linux: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=142

Comment: @Gusman hope the questioner thinks that is an "official" statement. That's only a comment from Miguel. I think even this blog post is more serious, http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Aug-29.html